# C# won't enumerate function which return's enumerator using SkipWhile

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have function which yield returns values. But i have strange behavior.

Code inside this function never call. So, my SkipWhile just exits without iterating enumerable.

But if i iterating using foreach, FirstOrDefult - everything is ok.

I tried different conditions inside SkipWhile predicate - no results.

So i can't understand - why.

Why SkipWhile just ignores enumerator.

```cs
public IEnumerable<LmaxTick> GetLmaxTicks(string instrument)
{
    using (var @if = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(_dbDir, $"Ticks{_lmaxMappings[instrument]}.csv")))
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(@if, Encoding.ASCII, true, 16 * 1024 * 1024))
    {
        var line = "";
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var (created, tick) = Csv.Csv<LmaxTick>.DeserializeRow(line.Split(','), true);
            if (!created)
            {
                continue;
            }

            yield return tick;
        }
    }
}


LmaxTick lmaxPrev = null;
lmaxTicks = lmaxTicks.SkipWhile(t =>
{
    if (DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds((long)t.TimestampMsec) >= date.Date + time.TimeOfDay)
    {
        return false;
    }
    lmaxPrev = t;
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it out myself.

Enumerators are lazy, so because i didn't request any items from them, they will do nothing.
In my case i need to use for example `First()`

Or, better solution

```
var lmaxEnumerator = lmaxTicks.GetEnumerator();
LmaxTick lmaxPrev = null;

while (lmaxEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    if (DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds((long)lmaxEnumerator.Current.TimestampMsec) >= date.Date + time.TimeOfDay)
    {
        break;
    }
    lmaxPrev = lmaxEnumerator.Current;
}
```

I call this code in a loop, so i can continue from current position of enumerator.